# Python multi-threading two parallel loops

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Let says I have two parallel block loops. What is the best way to run them in parallel using python. Currently I am experimenting with multi-threading using following program

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import serial
import os
from threading import Thread

ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=38400, timeout=None)

ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()

def getstrings(port):
    buf = bytearray()
    while True:
        b = port.read(1)
        if b == b'\x02':
            del buf[:]
        elif b == b'\x03':
            yield buf.decode('ascii')
        else:
            buf.append(b)

def tester():
    while 1:
        print('testing')

def values():
    count = ""
    tem = ""
    hv = ""
    counti = 0
    temi = 0
    hvi = 0

    while 1:
        for item in getstrings(ser):

        #if len(item) >= 10:
         #   continue

            if item[1] == "C":
                count = item.split('C')[1]
                counti=int(count[0:5])


            if item[1] == "T":
                tem = item.split('T')[1]     
                temi=int(tem[0:5])

            if item[1] == "H":
                hv = item.split('H')[1]
                hvi = int(hv[0:5])/10

            print ("HV="+str(hvi)+" "+"Count="+str(counti)+" "+"Temp="+str(temi))

t1 = Thread(target=values)
t2 = Thread(target=tester)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Only the second thread works. It doesn't print the values from second. This is the first time I am experimenting with multi-threading. Once, I understood how this will function then I intend to use this to design a GUI using Tkinter libraries. I want to use loop of my program along Tkinter main loop. Any suggestion where I might be making a mistakes.

Update:

Yes it thread 2 not thread 1. My mistakes sorry about that. But individually both threads work if I comments `t1.start()` or `t2.start()`. However, together only thread 2 prints the output.

Comment: I take it this is Python 2?

Comment: Have you done any reading on the GIL?

Comment: If this is Python 3, `test` is going to break because you made `print` a Python 2 statement, but it should be a function: `print('testing')`. Just trying to rule out the easy stuff. Depending on how you're running this script, the error could be getting redirected somewhere you can't see it.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but that doesn't help.

Comment: Try putting a try/except around the loop on `values` and print any exceptions that might have been raised.

Comment: Can you try replacing the second one with some `test2` which just prints something else. I just want to make sure both threads are at least running. Add more print statements in the second thread to see where it is getting stuck.

Comment: The python 2 print statement would raise a syntax error on python 3. This can't be it.

Comment: The "HV=..." stuff is printing but "Testing", which should be printing thousands of times, is not?

Comment: I suspect getstrings(port) is actually not yielding anything.

Comment: @HariMenon OP claims that the first thread works. I'm trying to get some clarification because the second thread is pretty much bullet proof and the first one is likely to have the problems. But OP appears not to be following his own question or has simply decided not to respond.